# change calculator..denominations (quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies). are not printing the correct amount

Tags: javascript

Need help denominations (quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies are not printing). Each denomination, dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, is suppose to print the correct  change due.

```js
function calculateChange(){
  var amountDue = document.getElementById('amount-due').value;
  var amountReceived = document.getElementById('amount-received').value; 
  ////////////////////////////////////
  //dollars to print dollar mount  
  dollars = Math.floor(amountReceived % amountDue);
  document.getElementById("dollars-output").innerHTML = dollars;
                
  var quarters = Math.floor(amountReceived% dollars);
  document.getElementById('quarters-output').innerHTML = quarters;
  // var quarters to print # of quarters in change
                
  var dimes = Math.floor(amountReceived% dollars);
  document.getElementById('quarters-output').innerHTML = dimes;
  // var dimes to print # of dimes in change
                
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  var nickels = Math.floor(amountReceived% dollars);
  document.getElementById('quarters-output').innerHTML = nickels;  
  //var nickels to print # of nickels in change////////////////////////////////////
  //math.floor to do math
  //var pennies to print # of pennies in change        
  var pennies = Math.floor(amountReceived% dollars);
  document.getElementById('quarters-output').innerHTML = pennies; 
  return; 
  // to return the output of code
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Is code supposed to put output of each step in a place on your webpage? `document.getElementById('quarters-output')` is used for each value so it will try and put them all in the same place. Could you clarify what the current output is, and what the expected output is?

Comment: include all the code in the codeblock